# onPause and onResume method using sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, onresume, onpause

So I am trying to save my SeekBar values onPause and then have them reappear onResume. My code works but for some reason only the first in the list is being saved. If I change reds SeekBar then that saves but nothing else, if I leave red at 0 and move green to 40 then that green will save but then if I change red, only red will save. I do not know why this is happening. I have to use onResume or onPause or else I would make my variables static.

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.graphics.Color;



public class ColorChooserActivity extends ActionBarActivity
implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    // define variables for the widgets
    private SeekBar redSeekBar;
    private SeekBar greenSeekBar;
    private SeekBar blueSeekBar;
    private SeekBar alphaSeekBar;
    private View colorView;
    private TextView colorTextView;

    //instance variable
    private int colorValue = 0;
    private int redValue = 0;
    private int greenValue = 0;
    private int blueValue = 0;
    private int alphaValue = 0;
    private String output;

    // define the SharedPreferences object
    private SharedPreferences savedValues;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_chooser);

        // get references to the widgets
        redSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.redSeekBar);
        greenSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.greenSeekBar);
        blueSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.blueSeekBar);
        alphaSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.alphaSeekBar);
        colorView = (View) findViewById(R.id.colorView);
        colorTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colorTextView);

        // add listeners
        redSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        greenSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        blueSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        alphaSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        // get SharedPreferences object
        savedValues = getSharedPreferences("SavedValues", MODE_PRIVATE);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_color_chooser, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      // save the instance variables
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savedValues.edit();
        editor.putInt("redValue", redValue);
        editor.putInt("greenValue", greenValue);
        editor.putInt("blueValue", blueValue);
        editor.putInt("alphaValue", alphaValue);
        editor.putInt("colorValue", colorValue);
        editor.putString("output", output);
        editor.commit();

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        //get the instance variables
        redValue = savedValues.getInt("redValue", redValue);
        greenValue = savedValues.getInt("greenValue", greenValue);
        blueValue = savedValues.getInt("blueValue", blueValue);
        alphaValue = savedValues.getInt("alphaValue", alphaValue);
        colorValue = savedValues.getInt("colorValue", colorValue);
        output = savedValues.getString("output", output);



        // set widgets
        colorView.setBackgroundColor(colorValue);
        colorTextView.setText(output);
        redSeekBar.setProgress(redValue);
        greenSeekBar.setProgress(greenValue);
        blueSeekBar.setProgress(blueValue);
        alphaSeekBar.setProgress(alphaValue);

        super.onResume();

    }

    // argb method
    public int argb(int a, int r, int g, int b){
        return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
    }

    //*****************************************************
    // Event handler for the SeekBar
    //*****************************************************
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
    {
        redValue = redSeekBar.getProgress();
        greenValue = greenSeekBar.getProgress();
        blueValue = blueSeekBar.getProgress();
        alphaValue = alphaSeekBar.getProgress();

        colorValue = argb(alphaValue, redValue, greenValue, blueValue);

        colorView.setBackgroundColor(colorValue);

        output = "Red: " + redValue + " Green: " + greenValue +
                " Blue: " + blueValue + " Alpha: " + alphaValue;

        colorTextView.setText(output);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
    }


}
```

Comment: You should use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() method for saving states and restoring states of activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `onProgressChanged` method. You have several seekbars, I suggest you implement a seperate `OnSeekBarChangeListener` for each one of them or check for the ids of the seekbar before saving its values.

Basically, you should have something like this in your `onCreate` method (based on an SO user's comment to your question):

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {


    switch (seekBar.getId()) {
    case R.id.redSeekBar:
        redValue = redSeekBar.getProgress();
        break;
    case R.id.greenSeekBar:
        greenValue = greenSeekBar.getProgress();
        break;
    case R.id.blueSeekBar:
        blueValue = blueSeekBar.getProgress();
        break;
    case R.id.alphaSeekBar:
        alphaValue = alphaSeekBar.getProgress();
        break;
    }

    colorValue = argb(alphaValue, redValue, greenValue, blueValue);

    colorView.setBackgroundColor(colorValue);

    output = "Red: " + redValue + " Green: " + greenValue + " Blue: "
            + blueValue + " Alpha: " + alphaValue;

    colorTextView.setText(output);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The listener is not the problem, It has to do with the sharedPreference object not storing more than one of the int values. Its weird because the colorValue and option String gets saved. If I make all my variables static and remove the onResume and onPause methods than the program works flawlessly. Its as it the sharedPreference object will not hold more than one int...

Comment: I just tested this code and I am able to retrieve the saved seekbar values after I close the app and open it again. The code you posted saves only the "last changed" seekbar value when the app is closed and opened again.

Comment: I finally see what you did there, the first draft you did was kind of confusing. This worked great, thanks!